# Return null model object from controller to view in order to clear fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP MVC controller, I call a web service to process some information. If there is no error message returned then I want to be able to display a success message but also reset the entire field.

I had thought that the best way to do this was to use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` on the error message and, if the message is empty, use a `new` statement to erase the values in the model object like so:

```
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.ErrorMessage))
        {
            agtPay = new AgentInformation();
        }

        return View(agtPay);
```

When I step through the code in Visual Studio, the fields in the view appear to all be `null` as they should be, however when the page loads the previous values are still present. Thinking this had something to do w/caching I placed the following tag at the top of the view.

```
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
```

Here's the code from the view w/an abbreviated `switch` statement:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AgentInformation(AgentInformation agtPay)
    {
        //redirect if security is not met.  
        if (!Security.IsAgent(User)) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 1 });

        try
        {
            //Run field validation and if anything found send back
            string msg = AgentInformationValidator.ValidateFields(agtPay);


            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msg))
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = msg;
                return View(agtPay);
            }

            //If valid send agtPay to web service
            AgentsClient webService = new AgentsClient();
            ReturnMessage returnMessage = new ReturnMessage();

            string userName = User.Identity.Name;
            userName = userName.Substring(Math.Max(0, userName.Length - 6));

            switch (agtPay.TransactionType)
            {
                case ("E"):
                    returnMessage = webService.EftUpdateByTaxid(true,
                                                                agtPay.RefNumType.ToString(),
                                                                agtPay.RefNumber,
                                                                agtPay.OwnerMasterAgentId,
                                                                agtPay.PaymentFrequency,
                                                                false,
                                                                agtPay.RoutingNumber,
                                                                agtPay.AccountType,
                                                                agtPay.AccountNumber,
                                                                REQUEST_SYSTEM,
                                                                userName);
                    break;
                .
                .
                .
                .
                case ("U"):
                    returnMessage = webService.UnenrollEft(agtPay.RefNumType.ToString(),
                                                           agtPay.RefNumber,
                                                           agtPay.OwnerMasterAgentId,
                                                           REQUEST_SYSTEM,
                                                           userName);
                    break;
                default:
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "There was an error processing your request: No transaction type specified";
                    break;
            }

            if (returnMessage.Success)
            {
                string[] msgArray = returnMessage.FriendlyMsg.Split(';');
                ViewBag.ReturnMessage = msgArray[0];

                if (msgArray.Length > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < msgArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage += msgArray[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = returnMessage.FriendlyMsg;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Monet", "From Agent Controller: \n\r|Ex Message| " + ex.Message + "\n\r|Stack Trace| " + ex.StackTrace);
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "An error has occurred, IT has been notified and will resolve the issue shortly!";
            SendEmail.ErrorMail(ex);
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.ErrorMessage))
        {
            agtPay = new AgentInformation();
        }

        return View(agtPay);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the initial request is a `POST`, so `Razor` is going to grab those values from the `ModelState`. However, you can override it by issuing this line before returning:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

After doing that the view should pull the values from the model you sent back.

However, I'm going to recommend that you more appropriately just issue a `RedirectToAction` because it appears to me you're just trying to get back to the `GET` state:

```
return RedirectToAction("AgentInformation");
```

instead of:

```
return View(agtPay);
```